# What can we know from this snippet code of rails observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observers

I'm new to rails, and reading some rails code: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/models/user_action_observer.rb#L1

```
class UserActionObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :post_action, :topic, :post, :notification, :topic_user

  def after_save(model)
    puts 'do something'
  end
end
```

What can we know from this code? e.g.

1. Because it's name is `UserActionObserver`, so it's a Observer of model `UserAction`?
2. It observe: `:post_action, :topic, :post, :notification, :topic_user`, what do these fields mean? The will be created or just some references to some fields of other model?
3. When will the method `after_save` will be invoked, and what is the `model` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observer class name can be any name.  What really matters is this line

```
observe :post_action, :topic, :post, :notification, :topic_user
```

which observes objects created under PostAction, Topic, Post, Notification and TopicUser

The `after_save` is called after creating and updating a record.  The passed argument is the actual object involved so it can be an instance of any of the 5 observed model.  Using `model` as the parameter name is a bit misleading so you should change that to something like `record`

UPDATE: from the api

Observers will by default be mapped to the class with which they share a name. So CommentObserver will be tied to observing Comment, ProductManagerObserver to ProductManager, and so on. If you want to name your observer differently than the class you’re interested in observing, you can use the Observer.observe class method which takes either the concrete class (Product) or a symbol for that class (:product)

Comment: `:post_action` means the file `post_action.rb` or it will be translate to a class name `PostAction`?